# Placing Three Names Horizontally in The Bottom of a Page

Tags: positioning, titles, thesis, signatures

I had made another post for this question but apparently there were a lot of mistakes in the MWE. So, I am interested into creating the red colored format which is included in the picture:

[image]

I can only think of something like a tabular in order to have this configuration but still I am not able to write a code for it. It is the page of my Master's Thesis where the professors have to sign in order for it to be valid.

I would like it to follow after my title page which is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.01mm} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\scalebox{0.6}{\includegraphics{PANEPISTIMIO-PATRON-logo-4xromo.jpg}}}
    \\[0.5cm]
    \bigskip  \bigskip
    \begin{huge}
    \textbf{{ΜΕΤΑΠΤΥΧΙΑΚΗ ΔΙΠΛΩΜΑΤΙΚΗ ΕΡΓΑΣΙΑ}}
    \end{huge}
    \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip    
    \\
    \begin{Huge}
    Εντροπία και Δυναμική Πολύπλοκων Συστημάτων
    \end{Huge}
    \\ \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
    \begin{LARGE}
    \textbf{Ευάγγελος Χ. Μητσοκάπας} 
    \end{LARGE}
    \\
    \bigskip  \bigskip \bigskip
    \begin{Large}
    \textbf{Επιβλέπων}:\\
    Αναστάσιος Μπούντης \\
    Καθηγητής Πανεπιστήμιου Πατρών
    \end{Large}
    \\
    \bigskip  \bigskip \bigskip
    \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
    \textbf{Σχολή Θετικών Επιστημών \\ 
        Τμήμα Μαθηματικών \\ \bigskip
        Μεταπτυχιακό Δίπλωμα Ειδίκευσης στα}\\
    \textsl{\guillemotleft Εφαρμοσμένα Μαθηματικά \guillemotright} 
    \\ \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
    {Πάτρα, Ιούλιος 2016}\\
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

How could I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this, using `tabularx`, `geometry`  and `arydshln`. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` since you load `mathtools`:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
%Για τα Μαθηματικά Σύμβολα
%%\usepackage{amsmath}%% needless (loaded  by mathtools)
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%Για την χρήση των Ελληνικών
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[top=3 cm,bottom=3 cm,left=3.3 cm,right=3 cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{bigints}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\mtcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\mtcleardoublepage}}
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.01mm}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\newcommand{\BigO}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{O}\bigl(#1\bigr)}} %to use the Big O for Taylor terms
%to use "norm" symbols
\usepackage{commath}
%to write the calligraphic letters of spaces
%\usepackage{calrsfs}%% needless
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\Ba}{\mathcal{B}}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\La}{\mathcal{L}}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

%%%\usepackage{epsfig} %%obsolete,  replaced by \includegraphics
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}%%autostyle
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{etoc}

\makeatletter    
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
{\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
\def\chapquote@author{#2}%
\parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
\itshape}
{\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tabularx, array, arydshln, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{setspace}

    \geometry{showframe}

    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \begin{titlepage}
    \singlespacing
    \newgeometry{noheadfoot, nomarginpar, margin=2.5cm,}
    \begin{center}
        {\raisebox{0pt}[0.9\height]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{logo-up-4colour-landscape}}}
        \\[3\baselineskip]
        \begin{huge}
        \textbf{ΜΕΤΑΠΤΥΧΙΑΚΗ ΔΙΠΛΩΜΑΤΙΚΗ ΕΡΓΑΣΙΑ}%
        \end{huge}
        \vspace{3\baselineskip}%6
        \\

        \begin{Huge}
        Εντροπία και Δυναμική Πολύπλοκων Συστημάτων
        \end{Huge}
        \\ [2\baselineskip]%3
        \begin{LARGE}
        \textbf{Ευάγγελος Χ. Μητσοκάπας}
        \end{LARGE}
        \\ [2\baselineskip]%3
        \begin{Large}
        \textbf{Επιβλέπων}:\\
        Αναστάσιος Μπούντης \\
        Καθηγητής Πανεπιστήμιου Πατρών
        \end{Large}
        \vfill%\\[3\baselineskip]%
        \textbf{Σχολή Θετικών Επιστημών \\
            Τμήμα Μαθηματικών \\ \bigskip
            Μεταπτυχιακό Δίπλωμα Ειδίκευσης στα}\\
        \textsl{\guillemotleft Εφαρμοσμένα Μαθηματικά \guillemotright}
        \\[2\baselineskip]%
       \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l>{\arraybackslash}X}
     Επιβλέπων:& Νικολάος Παπαστεργιάδης \\
      & Αν. Καθηγητής Πανεπιστημία Πατρών \\[1.5ex]
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      Εγκρίθηκε απο την τριμελή
      }
       \end{tabularx}\\
    \vfill%\vspace*{2ex}
     \begin{tabularx}{16cm}{lXlXl}
    \cdashline{1-1}\cdashline{3-3}\cdashline{5-5}
    \addlinespace
       \makecell[tc]{Ν. Παπαστεργιάδης \\ Αν. Καθηγητής \\ Πανεπιστημίου Πατρών}
      &~ & \makecell[tc]{Ν. Χατζής \\ Αν. Καθηγητής Α.Π.Θ.}
     &~ & \makecell[tc]{Α. Γεωργιάδης \\ Καθηγητής \\ Πανεπιστημίου Ιωαννίνων}
       \end{tabularx}\\
       \vfill%\vspace*{1cm}
        {Πάτρα, Ιούλιος 2016}%\\
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this confict in some way with \begin{enumerate}[(i)] ? I get this kind of error :/

Comment: It should not, in theory. Do you mean you added an `enumerate` environment in the title page?

Comment: Not in the title page but in the rest of the thesis. I have everything in one latex document.

Comment: I see you used the syntax `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]`. This can work only if you load the package with option`[shortlabels]`. My code loads it without any option.  In other words, maybe `enumerate` is loaded twice, with different options, and LaTeX doesn't like that.

Comment: Should I load one of them? Or how can I put the option    [shortlabels]?

Comment: Remove mine. I don't use it – I think it's there because it was in your post. And load the other with the option, then check the problem disappeared.

Comment: It now splits the title page into two pages :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42128/discussion-between-bernard-and-mitscaype).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `minipage`. I created a command, called `\frontSign`, which takes two arguments, the first being the title of the person, and the second the name of the individual. You can put more lines in if you want to. I don't actually speak this language, so I am unable to see if the output is okay, so you should probably do some formatting, like a smaller font, possible `\bfseries` for the title.

I also did some changes to the way you distributed your content, as some of it didn't have any effect, and some of it was repeated.

Here are some tips:

- You can group changes inside curly brackets `{content}`, so no need to write `\begin{huge}content\end{huge}`, just use `{\huge content}`. Of course, you can write it out like you do, for clarity.
- Repeated `\bigskip` on the same line doesn't have any effect. Use `\vspace{length}` instead.
- Instead of `\\` all over, you can just use an empty line.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.01mm} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\frontSign}[2]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \dotfill\\
        #1\\
        #2
    \end{minipage}%
    }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    %\vspace{2cm}
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-16x9}}
    \vspace{2cm}

    {\huge%
    \textbf{ΜΕΤΑΠΤΥΧΙΑΚΗ ΔΙΠΛΩΜΑΤΙΚΗ ΕΡΓΑΣΙΑ} 
    \vspace{2cm}

    Εντροπία και Δυναμική Πολύπλοκων Συστημάτων}

    {\large\bfseries%
    Ευάγγελος Χ. Μητσοκάπας


    Επιβλέπων:

    Αναστάσιος Μπούντης 

    Καθηγητής Πανεπιστήμιου Πατρών}

    Σχολή Θετικών Επιστημών 
        Τμήμα Μαθηματικών 

         \bigskip

        Μεταπτυχιακό Δίπλωμα Ειδίκευσης στα

    \textsl{\guillemotleft Εφαρμοσμένα Μαθηματικά \guillemotright} 

    \bigskip
    Πάτρα, Ιούλιος 2016


\end{center}%
\vfill
\frontSign{Professor of Bioligy}{John Doe}\hfill\frontSign{Professor of Chemistry}{Jimmy Doe}\hfill\frontSign{Professor of Mathematics}{Jane Doe\\Jamie Doe}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```